# How to access text data in a precomposition using Lottie web

Tags: javascript, json, lottie, bodymovin

I'm trying to control the text values of a .json file, exported using bodymovin.

At this moment, i succeeded in creating a flat 'template' exported from bodymovin, and changing the values in the bodymovin .json file using the function updateDocumentData.

But the only elements i can change are the elements that are in the main composition of After Effects. Now i would like to try and make a more difficult template where i work with pre-compositions in After Effects. How can i use updateDocumentData (or another function?) to change text values in deeper compositions.

```
function functionUpdate() {
        anim.playSegments([450, 460], true);
        const animElement = anim.renderer.elements[1];
        console.log(anim.renderer.elements[1])
        animElement.updateDocumentData({t: 'Test Text'});
    }

    const animData = 'js/data_test.json';
    const animContainer = document.getElementById('lottie-container');
    const anim = lottie.loadAnimation({
        container: animContainer, // The dom element that will contain the animation
        renderer: 'svg',
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false,
        path: animData // Path to the animation json
    });
```